# Make GUI Thread update GUI and other Thread do everything else (Java)

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create my first Android App and of course to not cause the UI-Thread to be blocked, I need to have another Thread do the work. But then how can I get the UI-Thread to update for example a View? This is probably a very basic and stupid question but I'm quite new to programming and completely new to Java.
I did not really find anything when searching except for Invoking but then I don't actually have the UI-Thread in a variable...? Can I get that somehow?
Thank you!

Comment: See e.g. [this page](https://www.google.com/aclk?sa=l&ai=DChcSEwio38nl_LX0AhWm6O0KHXXLDQ0YABAJGgJkZw&ei=u8ugYYTrBov0tAbZ_rqQCw&sig=AOD64_0lUFj5OPlZidQ0CsfNMU1snJ3DhA&q=&sqi=2&ved=2ahUKEwjEtL_l_LX0AhULOs0KHVm_DrIQqyQoAXoECAIQFA&adurl=) in the Android developer documentation.

Comment: use handlers for update views from child thread, https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler